# More Complex Than Necessary: Comparing and Counting Items in Arrays

Tags: arrays, object, typescript, count, compare

I have a group of arrays that represent categories. Each array is a category, and each item in the array is a subject, e.g.

```
4 Categories containing Subjects
['A','B','D']
['C']
['E','F']
['G','H','I','J']
```

I have another group of arrays. Each of these items has up to four possible subjects, e.g.

```
3 Items containing Subjects
['A','F']
['E','I','C']
['E','F','G']
```

I want to count the number of items for each category. In this case, the results should be:

```
Total Items: 3
Category 1: 1
Category 2: 1
Category 3: 3
Category 4: 2
```

3 items, some of which are in multiple categories. Some of my items have two subjects in one category, and that is where I am screwing up. My results are then:

```
Total Items: 3
Category 1: 1
Category 2: 1
Category 3: 4
Category 4: 2
```

My count for category 3 is off by 1 because my third item has two subjects in the same category, E and F.

**What I've Tried**

For reference, categories is an array of objects:

```
categories = [
  { name: string, subjects: string[], count: number }
]
```

Items are somewhat similar:

```
items = [
  { subjects: Subject[] }
]
```

And Subject is just:

```
{ id: string, name: string }
```

This is what I need to tweak:

```
categories.map(category => 
  category.subjects.map(categorySubject => {
    if(items.subjects.map(itemSubject => itemSubject.id)
      .some(val => itemSubject.indexOf(val) === 0)) {
        category.count++;
    }
  }));
```

I thought I was headed the right direction with some, but I need to find a way to both check if the item subjects are in the categories while not counting twice for items that have multiple subjects in a category. I know it is my approach that is the problem. I can't change the way items are formatted (yes, the IDs really are strings), but I could change the categories if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, this seems to work:

```
var categories: Array<{ name: string, subjects: Subject[], count: number }> = [];

type Subject = { id: string, name: string }

var items: Array<{ subjects: Subject[] }> = [];

function inItem(subject: Subject, item: { subjects: Subject[] }): boolean {
    return item.subjects.some(itemSubject => itemSubject.id === subject.id);
}

categories.forEach((category, index) => {
    let count = 0;

    for (let j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < category.subjects.length; i++) {
            if (inItem(category.subjects[i], items[j])) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(`Category ${ index + 1 }: ${ count }`);
});
```

([code with the data in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20categories%3A%20Array%3C%7B%20name%3A%20string%2C%20subjects%3A%20Subject%5B%5D%2C%20count%3A%20number%20%7D%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Acategories%20%3D%20%3Cany%3E%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%09subjects%3A%20%5B%7B%20id%3A%20'A'%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20id%3A%20'B'%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20id%3A%20'D'%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%09subjects%3A%20%5B%7B%20id%3A%20'C'%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%09subjects%3A%20%5B%7B%20id%3A%20'E'%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20id%3A%20'F'%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%09subjects%3A%20%5B%7B%20id%3A%20'G'%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20id%3A%20'H'%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20id%3A%20'I'%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20id%3A%20'J'%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%7D%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Subject%20%3D%20%7B%20id%3A%20string%2C%20name%3A%20string%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20items%3A%20Array%3C%7B%20subjects%3A%20Subject%5B%5D%20%7D%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aitems%20%3D%20%3Cany%3E%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%09subjects%3A%20%5B%7B%20id%3A%20'A'%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20id%3A%20'F'%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%09subjects%3A%20%5B%7B%20id%3A%20'E'%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20id%3A%20'I'%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20id%3A%20'C'%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%09subjects%3A%20%5B%7B%20id%3A%20'E'%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20id%3A%20'F'%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20id%3A%20'G'%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%7D%5D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20inItem(subject%3A%20Subject%2C%20item%3A%20%7B%20subjects%3A%20Subject%5B%5D%20%7D)%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0D%0A%09return%20item.subjects.some(itemSubject%20%3D%3E%20itemSubject.id%20%3D%3D%3D%20subject.id)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60Total%20Items%3A%20%24%7B%20items.length%20%7D%60)%3B%0D%0Acategories.forEach((category%2C%20index)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%09let%20count%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09for%20(let%20j%20%3D%200%3B%20j%20%3C%20items.length%3B%20j%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20category.subjects.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09if%20(inItem(category.subjects%5Bi%5D%2C%20items%5Bj%5D))%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09count%2B%2B%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09break%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09console.log(%60Category%20%24%7B%20index%20%2B%201%20%7D%3A%20%24%7B%20count%20%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B))

But this isn't really a good solution as it's not very easy to understand if you're not who wrote the code, or you in 2 months from now.
You should probably come up with a better solution, for example index it.

Just have a `CategoriesIndex` which holds all of the categories/subjects and through it you add/remove/change them. In it you can have the same arrays but also references from items to categories.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, but no one will be able to understand what is going on right away when they see this.

```
categories.map(category => category.count = 0);
let nextCategory = false;
let itemSubjects = items.map(item => item.subjects)
  .map(subjects => subjects.map(subject => subject.id));
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
  for(var j = 0; j < categories.length; j++){
    nextCategory = false;
    for(var k = 0; k < categories[j].subjects.length; k++){
      for(var l = 0; l < itemSubjects[i].length; l++){
        if(itemSubjects[i][l] === categories[j].subjects[k]){
          categories[j].count++;
          nextCategory = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(nextCategory === true){
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```